# Why did the hijacker tell the air attendant to use the "sing song accent you all do"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, hijack

In *Hijack* episode 4, there's this scene where the hijacker yells at one of the air attendants to go on the intercom to warn all the passengers to behave.

But then he tells the attendant to use "...that f***-ing stupid sing song accent you all do..." That air attendant clearly has an RP accent, or close enough to my ears. Have I misunderstood the accent? Or is there something else going on with the plot?

Comment: I think that by "accent", they mean "[cadence](https://www.suchavoice.com/blog/2019/03/07/the-art-of-voice-over-cadences/)". Flight attendants, and other public service personnel, often speak with a very distinctive cadence, and I think that's what the hijacker is referring to. I'm not sure I can elaborate enough to form a proper answer, nor have I watched the series in order to be certain that that's what the hijacker is referring to.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag0V_xSGZuc

Comment: Most people, including hijackers and screen writers, are not very precise with their word choices.